# Setting up a PHP environment using Atom ( for HTML+CSS+JS+PHP development)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql-workbench, atom-editor

I’m seeking your support and expertise today. I’ve started a project using html, css, and js and I'd need to add php to the file to enter & store data; I’m fresh to PHP programming- and before I begin to program my php file, I know I have to set up my environment for building php with Atom and storing my data to Workbench.

My question, how do I setup ATOM for PHP development using MySQL Workbench on my Mac to connect to a local host viewed index.html file, and allow the user to fill out my form (my program is a simple invoice for quotes) on a html file and send the info back to workbench?

How do I set up Atom, and what code do I use to connect my index.html file to the sql-workbench, or what do I have to do? What packages should I download, what steps do I take? any recommendations?

I tried researching on how to set up the environment but still lost as to what to do. (Also, I'm open to other platforms that work as well with ATOM- so keep that in mind in your response.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rename your index.html to index.php. With that you can insert php code within the file.
Here's some useful Atom packages to ease you for coding:

- https://atom.io/packages/atom-autocomplete-php (useful to
  autocommplete php codes)
- https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-html    (useful to
  autocommplete php codes)
- https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs (autocomple for javascript code)
- https://atom.io/packages/atom-html-preview (works only for .html page
  not php)
- https://atom.io/packages/project-manager (manage
  multiple projects of web development for example)

you need a webserver installed in your machine like [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) or [WAMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to run your php/mysql websites.

Comment: Thanks @Hanzouti- I had previously installed all the packages with the exception of project-manager which I'll add that now. I like the FTP package as well, but not sure how to run it and haven't read the documentation on that either. Regarding the preview package, I think it's fantastic- and by far my favorite package so far on ATOM- I enjoy the side by side view and auto refresh feature. Regrind the WAMP/MAMP- Can you provide a high level summary on how to set up a WAMP, or MAMP setup on a MAC?

Comment: Or things to watch out for when setting up the environment (best practices- I suppose?)

Comment: Documentation are always useful in this phase.
For XAMPP start with page: https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_osx.html
MAMP: https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/Installation/ . Here's a couple of videos for this matter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xnXHLHR3AE . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiA96L0zDXs

Comment: For PHP, does it have to be MyPhPmyAdmin or a different version? I also found this link see below for those interested going a different route. What do you think about installing Apache directly, opposed to MAMP? 

https://gist.github.com/dreamsparkx/45fba1a25d6b175283a456b19f935ca3

Comment: If you mean phpMyAdmin, it's different story. That tool is used to manage databases.